# How to search for an IP address in MediaWiki?

Tags: search, mediawiki

Entering an IP in the search box, even when enclosed in quotes, looks for user contributions with that IP. I'm trying to find it as text on a wiki page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the "contains..." option in the search dropdown.

Comment: Ah. I always thought that drop down meant that was what was being searched by just hitting enter.  Thanks!

Comment: It means that but it also forces a result list - ie. it disables jumping to the first result when the search engine decides it is a perfect match. Usually a perfect match means you typed the exact page name apart from case, but there are exceptions - IP addresses and MediaWiki: page names are always considered a perfect match, even if the page does not exist.

Comment: (For the benefit of people reading this answer and using some other skin, this is for the Vector skin. Other skins tend to have two different search buttons - such as "Search" and "Go" - instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Click on the [search icon](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Feedbin-Icon-home-search.svg) without to enter any text, then type the ip address ([example for 148.20.57.3](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=default&search=148.20.57.3&fulltext=Search)). Here if you want you can use quotes to be more specific.

**Note**: This not work for [Topic](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3APrefixIndex&prefix=&namespace=2600) pages (check [Advanced](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&search=&fulltext=Search&profile=advanced) option of the searcher for all supported namespaces).

Comment: That also works, but Tgr answered first and has less clicks to do the search, so I marked his answer as accepted.

Comment: @sdoca, actually the clicks are the same just different paths, but I'm agree Tgr was first :)